# Remove a specific field in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

My data looks like:

```
PHARMACY { 
    Name: "Walter", 
    City: "London" 
    UserQuestion: [
       { 
          text: "BlaBlaBla",
          type: "Prescription" 
       }, 
       { 
          text: "BlaBlaBla",
          type: "Medicine request"
       }, 
       { 
          text: "BlaBlaBla",
          type: "Prescription"
       } 
    ]
}
```

I have to remove from the Pharmacy Walter only the Questions regarding the "Prescription type" between the several questions, so i have to logically remove `UserQuestion[0]` and `UserQuestion[2]` .
I tried this code

```
db.pharmacy.update({Name:"Walter"}, {$unset: {type:"Prescription"}} , {multi: true});
```

but doesn't work, so I tried with the remove method

```
db.pharmacy.remove({$and: [{Name:"Walter"}, {"UserQuestion.type":"Prescription} ] } );
```

I hope my problem is clear, Thanks you.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" (which is a useless problem description), do you mean "doesn't update any documents", "causes an error" or something else? And can you show us the Pharmacy doc's `Schema`?

Comment: I mean that does simply nothing so does not update any documents in both cases. The pharmacy doc schema is: COLLECTION PHARMACY { objectId:{"..."} Name: "Walter", City: "London", UserQuestion {text, type}} So inside the collection of pharmacy there are questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.arrayFilters/)

Try this query:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "Name": "Walter"
},
{
  "$unset": {
    "UserQuestions.$[af].type": ""
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "af.type": "Prescription"
    }
  ],
  "multi": true
})
```

This query first find the element that match the `name`. After that, delete the field `type` using `$unset` for every element that match the `arrayFilter`. And this filter is set just below. We eant those element that `.type` is `Prescription`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/auilgYnXgeY)

Edit to explain why `$`operator doesn't works:

Note that using position operator `$` the query will not work because, as is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) this operator return only the first element that matches the query. And you want to update every element into array that matches, not only the first.

Example that doesn't work [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/naV0X1IDuyn)
Note how only one object remove the field `type`.

Comment: Thanks you so much but i tried and it updates 0 rows and does not remove the two questions

Comment: I have used lower case into variables. Check that fields matches with yours. By the way I will update fields to upper case to match your question.

Comment: I tried witch my fields and the in the terminal prints "Updated an existing record" but I don't know why do not remove the UserQuestions with the tipology "Prescription", they still be there

Comment: Are you using JS? Calls are asynchronous, maybe you output the values before update finish?

Comment: Nice! That is a good news. Also if the issue is resolved, mark question as accepted is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

What is the output you got with

```
db.pharmacy.update({Name:"Walter"}, {$unset: {type:"Prescription"}} , {multi: true});
```

Were there any matches? My guess is there were matches but no updates.

Try this?

```
db.pharmacy.update({"Name":"Walter"}, {$unset: {"UserQuestion.type":"Prescription"}} , {multi: true});

db.pharmacy.find({"UserQuestion.type":"Prescription"},{Name":1});
```

Comment: 1 existing record with this code is updated but the questions continue to be there and they have to be removed from the document